# Calendar app gone after flashing

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, calendar, rom

I have installed an ICS leak from my carrier (rom created by Motorola signed by my carrier but not released) and the calendar app has gone, I reinstalled the ROM from 2 different download sites and nothing, no one complains about this issue at all, some others just compalin some events don't appear but they have the app o.0

What can I do?

Comment: **Please don't double post!** If you want to add additional info to your question use the edit link below the question!

Answer (score 1):

The Official Calendar app, just like Google Maps, YouTube, etc., has been an independent app from the Android Stock ROM and published on Google Play.

Which means you can just download it via [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Has your calendar app really been wiped? (Try adding it as a shortcut from the app drawer.)

You can sometimes download an application from your handset manufacturer for your PC which provides a feature like "emergency firmware recovery". This should allow you to install the latest official release of Android.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you did this using a rooted phone. If that's the case, you should be able to find someone who has Calendar app, and manually push that to system/app and fix permissions.